# Use multiple NFS servers for a single directory

Tags: mount, nfs

I have to store some gigabytes of data in a single dir.
The structure is as follow :

```
/DATADIR
  - dataABC
  - dataXYZ
  - folder012/
  - folder456/
  - ...
```

If my hard disk is close to full, is there a way to increase the capacity using one (or several) NFS server(s), which would all be mounted with the same root (/DATADIR) ?
My goal is to avoid using subdirectories for newly mounted NFS servers. I don't want this :

```
/DATADIR
  - dataABC
  - dataXYZ
  - folder012/
  - folder456/
  - NFS-1/
    - dataMNO
    - folder789/
  - NFS-2/
    - dataPQR
    - folder234/
  - ...
```

I don't know if it's possible, but perhaps someone has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

until nfs4.1 is more common, take a look at glusterfs:

http://gluster.com/community/documentation/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/

Once you've mounted several NFS machines, IF that's what you're after, then you can present them through a single logical volume.

Comment: LVM is for block devices, and has nothing to do with NFS